# i get an error with return value in my script sql of stored proc

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I get 'A TOP or FETCH clause contains an invalid value' this error

"
Msg 1014, Niveau 15, État 1, Procédure dbo.sp_contacts_getcontacts, Ligne 24 [Ligne de départ du lot 0]
A TOP or FETCH clause contains an invalid value. "

I want to get contacts using stored procedure ,  this is the code of the SP

```
( @Id     uniqueidentifier  = NULL,
    @role   nvarchar(max)     = NULL,
    @IdCompany    uniqueidentifier  = NULL,
    @Active   bit     = 0, 
    @Page  int    = NULL,
    @PerPage   int  = NULL,


)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
     SELECT * 
     FROM [dbo].[Contacts] 
     LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Companies]    
     ON Contacts.[IdCompany] =  Companies.[IdCompany]
     WHERE
          (@Id is null or @Id = [IdContact])
    AND   (@role is null  or @role=contacts.[Role])
    AND   (@IdCompany  is null or @IdCompany  = [IdCompany])
    AND   (@Active = 0 or @Active = [Active])

    ORDER BY [IdContact] OFFSET ((@Page - 1) * @PerPage) ROWS FETCH NEXT @PerPage ROWS ONLY

END
```

Comment: Where are `@Page` and `@PerPage` declared and intialised?

Comment: Don't post images of code or error messages. Paste the **text** in the post.

Comment: Sorry i forget to copy them

Comment: You have parameters for the Page and the PerPage which are both optional parameters and can be NULL. If either of those are NULL your code will faill because you then saying OFFSET NULL which makes no sense. You should at least default values that would make for a valid query. Also, don't use the sp_ prefix...http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Answer (score 1):

I could be misunderstanding your question.
If you want to grab the results from that select, you'll need a table variable that matches the output of the sproc to Insert Into.

```
DECLARE @someTable TABLE(
    /* Whatever the output is of the sproc */
)

INSERT INTO @someTable
EXEC @return_value = dbo.nameOfYourSproc
```

You could also try creating a temp table from the results

```
INSERT INTO #someTable
EXEC @return_value = dbo.nameOfYourSproc
```

Although, my recommendation is to turn that SPROC into a table-valued function.

Comment: thank u for u answer ..but i have already a full table of contacts i just want to get those contacts

Comment: the table-valued function would have the same internal code as what the sproc has. you wold just call it  as if it was a table. `SELECT * FROM dbo.FetchContacts( /*your params*/ ) as contacts`

Answer (score 0):

The code was correct , i just did not insert values for page and perpage this way it show the error 'FETCH...'